# In "Only Lovers Left Alive," what does it mean that Eve and Ava are "sisters?"

Tags: vampire, only-lovers-left-alive

Halfway through the 2013 vampire movie *Only Lovers Left Alive*, Eve's "sister" Ava appears. Adam and Eve have this short exchange at 1:05:22:

> Eve:  Adam, she is my sister.
>
> Adam: Is she now.
>
> Eve:  Well, we are related by blood.

Is there any paratextual material that goes into detail what this means?

Eve & Ava see each other as family and close, and clearly something related to becoming a vampire has happened ("by blood"), which Adam does not necessarily see as them automatically being siblings.

Their origin could be something like:

- Both were turned by the same person;
- Eve turned Ava, and feels responsible for her;
- There was some family connection between the two, before either were turned. I doubt this one, as Eve is around 2000 years old ([Source](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt1714915/trivia)), and I think Ava is supposed to be considerably younger;
- Ava is a descendant of Eve, but since both are eternally youthful the term "sisters" could be more appropriate;
- There was some relation with Eve being an old Druid (same source as above), where the term sister could be applicable

but I am rather stretching the options here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implication is that Eve sired her, in the same way that she sired Adam. Both are thousands of years younger than she is, Ava by more than 2000 years and Adam by more than 2500 years. The film's star identified this bond as being '*related by blood*' but was surprisingly coy about outright stating it. Perhaps they have a common genesis (no pun intended) other than sharing blood with Eve, probably not.

> Q. Do you think Eve vampirized Adam?
>
> **Tilda Swinton:** *I wonder. Who knows? They are, as she would say, related by blood. Yeah, maybe.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Film Comment - Interview: Tilda Swinton](https://www.filmcomment.com/blog/interview-tilda-swinton/)</sup></sub>

Comment: Sweet, thanks for finding that interview! :)

Answer (score 1):

I see a different possibility.

In some vampire lores, vampires can mate and have children and one of the impacts is that the new vampire will age very slowly until he or she reaches full maturity.

This could explain a few things: why Ava is so very immature and acts like an adolescent or teenager despite being 300 hundred years old.

She could have been born a vampire and is literally still growing up. That could also be why Eve is patient with her the way you would be with your father or mother who had another kid much later and sees a certain cuteness in her antics. They didn't "grow up" together.

Just an alternate idea.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I can see this might be a possibility, but do you have any evidence that would support this?  That vampires can have children, for instance?  The more evidence you can provide in an answer the better it will be.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Eve sired Adam. It would make their relationship dynamic too one sided. I do believe she either sired Ava, though I don't see why she would, or, more likely, Ava is a distant relation, like great great great(ad infinitum)niece or cousin, this the "related by blood" comment. Also I think she's literally still very young, in terms of vampirism. maybe less than a hundred years old.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have any evidence for this?  Please note that the question didn't say that Eve sired Adam, that was a different answer, and you shouldn't use an answer to reply to another answer.